# Python Selenium - WebDriverWait until either titles are displayed

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to implement a wait by checking if the page title contains 'Page 1' like this

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.title_contains("Page 1"))
except TimeoutException as e:
    return
```

How can I modify this so it also checks for a page title of 'Page 2', so if either of those page titles show up then it passes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try below code:

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda x: 'Page 1' in driver.title or 'Page 2' in driver.title)
except TimeoutException as e:
    pass
```

Comment: How would this be adapted to take in a list of possible titles? Eg: ['Page 1', 'Page 2', 'Page 3']

Comment: This answer is not fully correct, I believe it should be ```WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda x: 'Page 1' in x.title or 'Page 2' in x.title)``` (note that it's `x.title` instead of `driver.title`); the point is that you should operate on the driver reference passed in to the condition rather than the reference to the driver in the outer scope.


And regarding @OscarVanL 's question - it can be as easy as ```WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda x: any(t in x.title for t in ['Page 1', 'Page 2', 'Page 3']))```.